# Error when calling BigQuery stored procedure from SSIS using Simba odbc driver

Tags: ssis, google-bigquery

I’m trying to call a BQ stored procedure in SSIS using Simba odbc driver and getting an error

> [Execute SQL Task] Error: Executing the query "CALL
>   `mhpmvp.MCR_V01_M_MA..." failed with the following error:
>   "[Simba][BigQuery] (70) Invalid query: Positional query parameters are
>   not supported in scripts". Possible failure reasons: Problems with the
>   query, "ResultSet" property not set correctly, parameters not set
>   correctly, or connection not established correctly.**

- The call worked in query editor
- The sp doesn’t take parameters and doesn’t return anything
- The connection is fine. It works if I run a select query

  ### [image: Execute Query][image: query editor]

Comment: Have you tried calling your procedure without parentheses?

Comment: @rmesteves i did . Syntax error: Expected "(" or "." but got ";". i've tried multiple combinations. with and without `. fully qualifying with project id. No luck !!

Comment: Have you tried those variations with brackets? 
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/native-client-odbc-stored-procedures/calling-a-stored-procedure?view=sql-server-ver15#delimiters-in-call-statements

Answer (score 0):

I'm from Google Cloud Platform Support.

I can see that this issue is already being investigated internally. I created a [Public Issue](https://issuetracker.google.com/148491521) in our Tracker regarding this, so you can [subscribe](https://developers.google.com/issue-tracker/guides/subscribe#subscribe_to_an_issue) to or [star](https://developers.google.com/issue-tracker/guides/subscribe#starring_an_issue) it to receive a notification whenever an update is posted.